# Bytes sent from app are not read properly on server

Tags: java, android, file-upload, outputstream

I am uploading file using [this](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service) library (android-upload-service) from Android. It works fine on `local server` for all types of media but when I send it to `Java Server`, server reads on last few bytes. e.g. for a file of **5 MB**, server reads only **71 bytes**.

For same server, files can be uploaded from **iOS device**. What can possibly be wrong when I upload file?

This is the code I use to upload file on server

```
    MultipartUploadRequest request = new MultipartUploadRequest(context, BuildConfig.SERVER_URL + EndPoints.FILE_UPLOAD);
    if (report.isFileUri()) {
        request.addFileToUpload(new File(report.getContentUri().getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), "file");
    } else {
        request.addFileToUpload(report.getContentUri().toString(), "file");
    } 

    RequestHeaders requestHeaders = new NactaEaseConfig().defaultHeaders(context);
    if (requestHeaders == null) {
        throw new Exception("Required headers are not available. Quitting.");
    }

    request.addHeader(EaseRequest.TOKEN_KEY, EaseTokenManager.getToken(context));

    Map<String, String> headers = requestHeaders.get();
    for (String key : headers.keySet()) {
        request.addHeader(key, headers.get(key));
    }

    request.addParameter("reportedLive", report.getLiveReportingString())
            .addParameter("draftsCreatedDate", report.getFormattedTimeForUpload())
            .addParameter("incident_type", report.getReportType())
            .addParameter("file", report.getFileName())
            .addParameter("incident_location", report.getCompleteAddress())
            .addParameter("app_user_location", report.getLocation())
            .addParameter("show_identity", report.getShareNumberString())
            .addParameter("description", report.getDetails())
            .addParameter("mobile_number", user.getMobileNumber())
            .addParameter("area_name", report.getArea())
            .addParameter("city_name", report.getCity())
            .addParameter("content_type", report.getServiceContentType())
            .setMaxRetries(0);
    request.startUpload();
```

And these are the logs I get while uploading file.

```
D/UploadService: UploadRequest - null or empty upload ID. Generating it
D/UploadService: UploadRequest - Created new upload request to http://124.109.32.137:8080/NACTA/REST/Communicator/FileUpload with ID: 1034ab15-a10c-41c6-8f36-5697b4dffb81
D/UploadService: MultipartUploadRequest - Auto-detected MIME type for content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A146 is: video/mp4
D/UploadService: MultipartUploadRequest - Using original file name: VID_20171216_223940.mp4
I/UploadService: UploadService - Starting service with namespace: com.es.tatheer, upload pool size: 2, 5s idle thread keep alive time. Foreground execution is enabled
D/UploadService: UploadService - Successfully created new task with class: net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadTask
D/UploadService: FileUploader - Starting upload task with ID 1034ab15-a10c-41c6-8f36-5697b4dffb81
D/UploadService: MultipartUploadTask - 466841
D/UploadService: OkHttpStackConnection - creating new connection
D/UploadService: UploadTask - Broadcasting upload progress for 1034ab15-a10c-41c6-8f36-5697b4dffb81: 103 bytes of 468370
D/UploadService: UploadTask - Broadcasting upload progress for 1034ab15-a10c-41c6-8f36-5697b4dffb81: 361928 bytes of 468370
D/UploadService: MultipartUploadTask - 468323
D/UploadService: UploadTask - Broadcasting upload progress for 1034ab15-a10c-41c6-8f36-5697b4dffb81: 468370 bytes of 468370
D/UploadService: FileUploader - Server responded with HTTP 200 to upload with ID: 1034ab15-a10c-41c6-8f36-5697b4dffb81
D/UploadService: UploadTask - Broadcasting upload completed for 1034ab15-a10c-41c6-8f36-5697b4dffb81
D/UploadService: UploadService - All tasks completed, stopping foreground execution
I/UploadService: UploadService - Service will be shut down in 10000ms if no new tasks are received
D/UploadService: OkHttpStackConnection - closing connection
I/UploadService: UploadService - Service is about to be stopped because idle timeout of 10000ms has been reached
D/UploadService: UploadService - Stopping foreground execution
D/UploadService: UploadService - UploadService destroyed
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. You should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Code snippets and logs are added.

Comment: `but when I send it to Java Server, se` Where would that be? Why did you compare it with a local server?

Comment: Can you name the library you used? Why do you force us to follow a link?

Comment: This is the server we use for our app. I tried to verify if things are working fine on local server (PHP).

Comment: Its android-upload-service. Sorry for the link. I have added name now.

Comment: It is unclear where your java server is running. Local or somewhere on the internet.

Comment: `new File(report.getContentUri().getPath()).getAbsolutePath()` ? That does nothing. You could as well replace that by `report.getContentUri().getPath()`. But then... how would we know what is in it? What is the value of `report.getContentUri().getPath()`?

Comment: It's not local. I have tried `report.getContentUri().getPath()` too.

Comment: You are not seriously answering my questions.

Comment: It's in the logs. `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A146`

Comment: @greenapps problem is not in reading file from mobile. It happens when I send it to server.

Comment: On the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional information, the first I will suspect will be that you're sending the content as multipart. A few questions then:

- Does your Java server handle multipart content? If not, that's probably your problem.
- Could you check if the 71 bytes you mention are really the last bytes of the file you're sending? If it is, then maybe the problem is that the content is being sent as chunked encoding and the server is only keeping the last chunk.

Given you're using HTTP and not HTTPS, you can easily use a tool like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) to diagnose this. Can be also used to compare your iOS and Android apps, as I understand they are using different libraries and maybe different data encodings.

Comment: Thanks @Xavier for your response. What can be the reason for ` chunked encoding and the server is only keeping the last chunk.`? I have tried both streaming modes, chunked and fixed length but server gets same bytes.

Comment: Then the more likely cause is your server not handling multipart properly. Use Charles proxy to compare Android and iOS apps.

Comment: Ok I will. Thanks for your time.